# SimpleForm custom title for input element

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

How can I add my own name to an input, e.g. a textbox? 
i.e. how can I customize the input name that is displayed beside an input?

Here is my code:

```
- title "Add a NEO"

= simple_form_for @neo do |f|
    = f.input :name
    br
    - for obs in @observations do
        = simple_form_for obs do |o|
            table 
                tr
                    td = o.input :ra
                    td = o.input :dec
    = f.button :wrapped, "Create NEO"
```

I would like to specify text for `o.dec` and `o.ra`. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean the label? You should probably read the doc.

Comment: Ah, yes, thx. I forgot that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- title "Add a NEO"

= simple_form_for @neo do |f|
    = f.input :name
    br
    - for obs in @observations do
        = simple_form_for obs do |o|
            table 
                tr
                    td = o.input :ra, :label => "Right Ascension"
                    td = o.input :dec, :label => "Declination"
    = f.button :wrapped, "Create NEO"
```

Comment: You can also use simple_form_en.yml (or any other language), and set your labels there, so that you keep your html clean.